# jquery or ashx not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ashx

I am using a ajax file upload control.

It is creating this html:

```
<form action="/pages/handlers/asyncfileuploadhandler.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="ajaxUploader-iframe-1397144545">
  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="mindvoice">
  <input type="file" id="imageFile" style="display: block; width: 80%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
</form>
```

And the target is:

```
<iframe width="0" height="0" style="display:none;" name="ajaxUploader-iframe-1397144545" id="ajaxUploader-iframe-1397144545"></iframe>
```

The form is submitted using `.submit()`.

My ashx handler:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="AsyncFileUploadHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using Nettpals.Core;
public class AsyncFileUploadHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var file = context.Request.Files[0]; // ArgumentOutOfBoundException
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know how to handle the file.

I'm using jquery [ajaxfileupload](https://github.com/jfeldstein/jQuery.AjaxFileUpload.js/)

So what should I do to grab the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked. Just added a `name` property to the `<input type="file">` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile"/>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="UploadFile();"/>
```

**JQuery:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        function UploadFile() {
    var fileName = $('#uploadFile').val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, '');
                       if (fileName != "") {
                        $.ajaxFileUpload({ url: 'AjaxFileUploader.ashx',
                            secureuri: false,
                            fileElementId: 'uploadFile',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (data, status) {
                               if (typeof (data.error) != 'undefined') {
                        if (data.error != '') {
                            alert(data.error);
                        } else {
                            alert('Success');
                        }
                    }
                },
                  error: function (data, status, e) {
                                alert(e);
                            }
                        }
                        )
                    }
}
});
</script>
```

For further reference, please see the below link.

[File Upload Without Using Any Asp Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655618/file-upload-without-using-any-asp-controls/22655715#22655715)